# Получить исходный код страницы

Tags: android, java

В `Java` на `Android` нужно получить исходный код запрашиваемой страницы (например `yandex.ru`).

Пробовал это делать через стороннюю библиотеку `Jsoup`, но этот способ мне не очень подходит. Есть глюки с либой.

Есть способ сделать это при помощи стандартных библиотек? И как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот к примеру небольшая статейка: [Android HTTP Access - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html). А так - гуглить на тему [httpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) - класс достаточно стандартный.